# Why am I getting "no such file or directory" when running fs.readdirSync() using nodejs and webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I decided to convert my nodejs app to using webpack (with typescript). Webpack compiles fine, but when I run `node dist/index.js` I get an error that file or directory is not found. The function this is about is as follows:

```
  private loadControllers() {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "Controllers"));
    for (let file of files) {
      require(path.join(__dirname, "..", "Controllers/" + file));
    }

    // routes array gets automatically populated upon each require() of a controller
    for (let route of routes) {
      this.#server.app[route.method](route.path, route.response);
    }
  }
```

It gets an error on fs.readdirSync. What do I do?

Comment: Can you provide us with the directory structure of your project?

Comment: webpack has probably completely changed the structure of your files and you don't have the directory structure you wanted to.  Why are you using webpack at all for server-side code?